# What is the best way to insert my age in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

"When I was 25yrs old, 25years-old / 25 year-old I entered a university building at night through an open window with the intent of burgling it as I wanted to get myself sent to prison". What is the correct way to insert my age in this sentence please? Thank you in advance

Comment: *When I was 25 years old* (no dash needed), *When I was 25*, and *At 25* all work. If you want *When I was a 25-year-old*,  the dashes come in.

Answer (score 1):

You should always hyphenate something like 25-year-old.

OR

When I turned Twenty five...

Example, She looks like an 18-year-old, you're using that hyphenated phrase with the indefinite article in a pronominal sense. It really means "an 18-year-old girl, so it's like a substitute pronoun.

Visit this for more info:
https://www.english-to-go.info/english-grammar-tips-year-or-years/